# ResponseBody as a list of objects - 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: ajax, json

I am trying to get the list of objects from ajax request and getting internal server error. It was working in the morning, but now it doesn't. 
Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'get',
    url : 'http://localhost:8080/FootballManager/draft/' + leaguename
            + '/players',
    dataType : "json",
    data : {
        "leaguename" : leaguename
    },
    contentType : "application/json",
    cache : false,
    success : function(data) {
         drawTable(data);   
    },
    error : function(XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("error= " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Spring mvc controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "{leaguename}/players", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers = "Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody
List<Players> getPlayers(@RequestParam("leaguename") String leaguename,HttpSession session) {
    try {
        //list of players
        return players;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception: ", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

UPD. It's strange, but it works with other's objects list, and it also strange, that if I create all objects manualy (like new Player()) and set the same fields with setters and add all objects in the list, it works, but if I obtain this objects from DB via hibernate, I get this error

Comment: What is the actual error? :) 500 is not an error explanation, it just means the server threw an error. So, open chrome dev tools, enable ajax logging, reload the page,and look for the 500 error, click on it, click view result, and read what the actual server error is.

Comment: 500 (Internal Server Error) that's all in ajax logging :(

Comment: It's your server so what about when you run it in debug what is the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eager isn't solution. It's workaround with drawbacks. Your problem is, I think, your collection isn't loaded and outside of your transaction you (or your serializer) doesn't have access to db. One of the solutions is to use DTO's to transfer your data to client and read your data in it. It's heard also like a workaround, but in practice you will have often specialized and restricted views for consuming at client side.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Changing fetchType to Eager solved this problem